# ASP Table doesnt save state

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created an ASP Table Control and added a row to it programatically. I then repeated the process to add another row. The first row that I added disappeared and only the newest row is being displayed. Is there a property that needs to be set to allow the state of the table to be saved?

EDIT:

All I do is click a button on the page and it adds a row to the table. Repeated clicks of the button only add one from to the table. If it helps, here is the function that adds the rows.

```
 Protected Sub addItemButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'get the id of the item they selected
    Dim id As String = CType(sender, Button).Text
    'clear out the data being displayed
    gridViewItemSearchItems.DataSource = Nothing
    gridViewItemSearchItems.DataBind()
    'add this item to the line table
    Dim itemToAdd As Item = gp.Items.GetItemByKey(id)

    Dim tableRow As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow()

    Dim cellId As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellId.Text = itemToAdd.Key.Id

    Dim cellDesc As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellDesc.Text = itemToAdd.Description

    Dim cellMSRP As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellMSRP.Text = gp.Items.GetItemMSRP(itemToAdd.Key)

    Dim cellCost As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellCost.Text = itemToAdd.CurrentCost.Value

    Dim cellUnitPrice As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellUnitPrice.Text = itemToAdd.StandardCost.Value

    Dim cellDiscount As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellDiscount.Text = "12%"

    Dim cellQuantity As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
    cellQuantity.Text = "1"

    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellId)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellDesc)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellMSRP)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellCost)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellUnitPrice)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellDiscount)
    tableRow.Cells.Add(cellQuantity)

    tblItems.Rows.Add(tableRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you adding the rows (in what event)? Could you post your code?

Comment: @CAbbott Its done in a after a button is clicked. So after in an OnClick function

Answer (score 3):

Since you're adding the rows to your table dynamically, they have to be re-created on each successive post-back.

Look at this answer for an explanation as to why dynamically added controls can disappear: [ASP.NET dynamically created controls and Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216329/asp-net-dynamically-created-controls-and-postback)

**EDIT**: It is possible to dynamically add controls during a post-back, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883074/asp-net-repeating-input-boxes-on-the-client-side-using-repeater/1883196#1883196) shows a way to do that using `ViewState`. Although, this does become very cumbersome. You might want to re-think the design of the page.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. I am going to give this a shot now.